# Is there an equivalent to gnuplot's "epslatex" in R?

Tags: r, latex, gnuplot, figure

I am looking for an R environment that can produce an **eps** figure and a **tex** file just as the *epslatex* environment in `gnuplot`.

**Background**

The following code shows a `gnuplot` file (the one I am wondering if I can replace with an R file). The output from `gnuplot` is two files: *figure.tex* and *figure.eps*.

```
set terminal epslatex color solid
set output "/path/to/report/figure.tex"

set xlabel "2$\\theta$"
set ylabel "Counts"
set xrange [20:60]
set yrange [300:14000]
# Plot col 1 against col 2, add vertical gap, e.g. (1000+($2))
plot 'file1.txt' using 1:2           title '<A-TITLE>' with lines, \
     'file2.txt' using 1:(1000+($2)) title '<B-TITLE>' with lines, \
     'file3.txt' using 1:(2000+($2)) title '<C-TITLE>' with lines, \
     'file4.txt' using 1:(3000+($2)) title '<D-TITLE>' with lines, \
```

Note how the graphical output from `gnuplot` (below) does not contain any text.
The text is added by typesetting the LaTeX article/book/etc. in which the file *figure.tex* file (not stack overflow friendly) is included.

[image]

**Question:** Can R do the same for me?

Alternative approaches in other languages is also appreciated. However, consistent typesetting of fonts and mathematical notation (I have my own LaTeX macros for this) is an absolute must!

Comment: You can produce TeX files with embedded R code using knitr or Sweave.

Comment: Alternatively I can recommend gnuplot ;) Seriously, do you have any special reason for not using gnuplot anymore?

Comment: Myself, absolutely none, in fact I think gnuplot is brilliant!

However, it is difficult to "inspire the masses" to use gnuplot. R, on the other hand, has wonderful graphics capabilities and is much more "plug and play". A massive improvement compared to python and especially matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, you can easily produce `.tex` files using [Sweave](https://www.statistik.lmu.de/%7Eleisch/Sweave/). The simplest way to do this is to utilize the [RStudio IDE](http://www.rstudio.com/) which has support for both Sweave and MFR (Markdown For R).

Sweave allows you to embed chunks of R code inside a `.tex` file; the R code is run to produce output, and then the file is compiled (not sure if that's exactly the right word) from `.tex` to whatever format you want.

If you want the output image to be a separate file from the output `.tex` you can do that easily in Sweave, and the files will generally be in a separate directory. You will need to examine the chunk options to do so.

EDITED TO ADD: As noted below by [Alex A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3005513/alex-a), the `knitr` package was developed to address some of the oddities of Sweave, and is tightly integrated into RStudio and can address some of what you want as well.

Comment: Note that [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr) is also support in RStudio and was developed to address some of the shortcomings and syntactic oddities of Sweave.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will have a look at this answer :)